# How to check if a number starts with other numbers in perl

Tags: perl

i need help with creating a function that get a random number(for example 45789277) 
And will check if the number above starts with one of list of number that are same always
(for example [1,2,45,757, 3, 7466])

If the number given is 55366363 and the list is [1,4,3] the function will return False, if the list is [6535,55,1,8] the function will return a True
*there is not a chance that the number will start in two numbers from the list
*the first digit of the number given will never be 0
*in list there going to be diffrent length numbers(one/two/three/four digits)
* the number given will always have more digits then the numbers in the list

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can join all the prefixes into a regex and match the random number against it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub prefix_in_list {
    my ($needle, $haystack) = @_;
    my $regex = join '|', @$haystack;
    return $needle =~ /^(?:$regex)/
}

use Test::More tests => 3;

ok prefix_in_list(45789277, [1, 2, 45, 757, 3, 7466]);

ok ! prefix_in_list(55366363, [1, 4, 3]);

ok prefix_in_list(55366363, [6535, 55, 1, 8]);
```

Or, if you like a numeric solution:

```
sub compute_length {
    my ($n) = @_;
    return int(log($n) / log 10)
}

sub prefix_in_list {
    my ($needle, $haystack) = @_;
    for my $prefix (@$haystack) {
        my $start = $needle;
        my $divider = 10 ** (compute_length($start) - compute_length($prefix));
        return 1 if int($start / $divider) == $prefix;
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: the numeric one probably would barf if any item in the haystack is longer than (or maybe even the same length as) the needle ;) Also, you can use the `compute_length` difference to create a power of 10 that gets you the right amount to divide by in a single shot.

Comment: @Tanktalus: Thanks, removed the loop from the numeric solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [`substr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html):

```
# Checks if a number $num has a prefix given by an item in @$list
sub starts_width {
    my ( $num, $list ) = @_;

    for (@$list) {
        return 1 if (substr $num, 0, length $_) eq $_;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively as @choroba mentioned, [`index`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) can be used:

```
return 1 if (index $num, $_) == 0;
```

Note that `index` will scan the whole string even if it did not find a match at position 0. So the most efficient solution of `substr` and `index` will most likely depend on your data.

Comment: @choroba Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my answer. A drawback of the `index` solution could be that it scans the whole string even if a match is not found at position zero.

Comment: Writing this for the next people come here. What ill probably do, is to use the index with an if, if the index is not 0 i will ignore it, so it will be a good solution...